# Selenium does not install Firefox addon due to "Add-on uBlock0@raymondhill.net is not correctly signed"

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, firefox-addon

Using Selenium, I want to start up Firefox with a set of extensions already installed using:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.addExtension(new File("path/to/firex_proxy-5.3.1-fx.xpi"));
profile.addExtension(new File("path/to/uBlock0@raymondhill.net.xpi"));
profile.addExtension(new File("path/to/ublock_origin-1.22.2-an+fx.xpi"));

FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
return new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

But the browser starts up with no extensions.

In the logs I can see:

```
addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on divanproger@gmail.com in app-profile
addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on uBlockOrigin@1.22.2 in app-profile
addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on uBlockOrigin@1.22.3.18 in app-profile

addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   New add-on uBlockOrigin@1.22.2 installed in app-profile
addons.xpi-utils    WARN    Add-on uBlock0@raymondhill.net is not correctly signed.
addons.xpi-utils    WARN    Add-on uBlock0@raymondhill.net is not correctly signed.
addons.xpi-utils    WARN    addMetadata: Add-on uBlockOrigin@1.22.2 is invalid: Error: Invalid addon ID: expected addon ID uBlockOrigin@1.22.2, found uBlock0@raymondhill.net in manifest(resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIDatabase.jsm:2715:15) JS Stack trace: addMetadata@XPIDatabase.jsm:2715:15

addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   New add-on divanproger@gmail.com installed in app-profile
addons.xpi-utils    WARN    Add-on divanproger@gmail.com is not correctly signed.
addons.xpi-utils    WARN    Add-on divanproger@gmail.com is not correctly signed.
addons.xpi-utils    WARN    addMetadata: Add-on divanproger@gmail.com is invalid: Error: Extension divanproger@gmail.com is not correctly signed(resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIDatabase.jsm:2725:15) JS Stack trace: addMetadata@XPIDatabase.jsm:2725:15

addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   New add-on uBlockOrigin@1.22.3.18 installed in app-profile
addons.xpi-utils    WARN    Add-on uBlock0@raymondhill.net is not correctly signed.
addons.xpi-utils    WARN    Add-on uBlock0@raymondhill.net is not correctly signed.
addons.xpi-utils    WARN    addMetadata: Add-on uBlockOrigin@1.22.3.18 is invalid: Error: Invalid addon ID: expected addon ID uBlockOrigin@1.22.3.18, found uBlock0@raymondhill.net in manifest(resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIDatabase.jsm:2715:15) JS Stack trace: addMetadata@XPIDatabase.jsm:2715:15
```

I downloaded the extensions from https://addons.mozilla.org/
I also copied one of the xpi files from my current profile folder and it did not make any difference.
I also used downloaded uBlock xpi from https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/releases and again no difference at all.

I have googled and could not find a clear answer that would work in my case. 
Can someone help to make my selenium firefox instance start up with at least [uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/) plugin installed?

System details:

- Running on Windows 10
- Firefox v69.0.1 (64-bit)
- Geckodriver version 0.25
- Selenium version 3.141.59 - also tried with version 4.0.0-alpha-2

Comment: late response: You may need developer edition of FF for installing addons from local packages.

Answer (score 0):

At almost 8 months later and with 166 views, I hope this proves to be the solution.

Regardless of the XPI or source, I received the same message:

```
addons.xpi-utils    WARN    addMetadata: Add-on uBlockOrigin@1.27.10 is invalid: Error: Invalid addon ID: expected addon ID uBlockOrigin@1.27.10, found uBlock0@raymondhill.net in manifest(resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIDatabase.jsm:2715:15) JS Stack trace: addMetadata@XPIDatabase.jsm:2715:15
```

This made no sense, since I could install any xpi while the controlled browser was open. It was just a case of going to `about:addons` and installing it by hand. This leads me to believe there's a bug in the web driver or elsewhere.

So I figured, what if I just patch the xpi myself? I had already spent how many minutes, what was another 2 or 3?

1. Copy the xpi to somewhere, and change it from .xpi to .zip
2. Right click and extract to a folder
3. Open the `manifest.json` file in a text editor
4. Change `"id": "uBlock0@raymondhill.net"` to `"id": "uBlockOrigin@1.27.10"`
5. Inside the folder, select all the files and add to a zip archive
6. Change the file's zip extension to xpi
7. Point selenium to use this patched xpi.

You should now receive the message:

```
addons.xpi  WARN    Invalid recommendation for uBlockOrigin@1.27.10: {"addon_id":"uBlock0@raymondhill.net","states":["recommended"],"validity":{"not_after":"2025-05-28T10:22:58Z","not_before":"2020-05-28T04:22:58Z"},"schema_version":1}
```

But all is good, as uBlock Origin loads as expected.

[image: uBlock Origin Installed]